# Single Sided Buffer Error QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, buffer

I have delineated a shoreline and created an offset "buffer" of 75' and 250'. When projected onto the screen it appears as though a computation error has occurred and the buffers extend onto the left of the baseline. What may have caused this? I have edited the buffer nodes after the fact to trim out these shapes but would like to know for future reference. [image]

Comment: Can you share the shoreline data?

Comment: It's a bit tricky to tell which layer is which, because you have two buffer layers with the same name and identical styling.